# how to remove nested array value and get all values in a collection in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to delete a record in a nested array in a collection

mongodb collection is having the following records

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("589b043abc2f5a467c13303b"),
  "user_id" : ObjectId("5874c174c813822341cb59a7"),
  "filename" : [
   {
     "url" : "images/product_images/file-1486554170465.jpeg",
     "_id" : ObjectId("589b043abc2f5a467c13303c")
   },
   {
     "url" : "images/product_images/file-1486554306440.jpeg",
     "_id" : ObjectId("589b04c2bc2f5a467c13303f")
   }]
}
```

In that record i need to delete the fist url , which is under in filename array ,then i need the remaining url values , is there any way to implement this , kindly please help me . Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator. In your case:

```
Collection
    .update({
        "_id": ObjectId("589b043abc2f5a467c13303b")
    }, {
        "$pull": {
            "items": {
                "_id": ObjectId("589b043abc2f5a467c13303c")
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Elamparithi.P Buy why? This does exactly what you asked and should be (by far) the fastest way. I do not really see why you need/want another way?

Comment: @Elamparithi.P The remaining data still exists in the document. I have added an example of how your sample document will look after executing the query.

Comment: sorry for the confusion , i need to delete the url with the (**url**) id which is under in filename array

Comment: @Elamparithi.P What are you trying to achieve? Update your question with clear examples because I have no idea what you are trying to say at the moment...

Comment: i need to delete the url with these id ObjectId("589b043abc2f5a467c13303c") , ObjectId("589b04c2bc2f5a467c13303f") not a main id are understand now or not

Comment: I think its not suitable with my need .. I need to delete the url with the url _id , u tell about the main object id ..

Comment: @Elamparithi.P Wat is the url _id?

Comment: every url has it own object id , i write in my question .

Comment: @Elamparithi.P In the `$pull` part the _id is the ObjectId of the url? Or do you mean the first object of the update function?

Comment: @Elamparithi.P Do you have any feedback on this matter?